# postgresql update row to fixed digit number

Tags: sql, postgresql, append

I am beginner in sql query and I am trying to update my rows like that:

1--->0001

15-->0015

254-->0254

1458-->1458

My column's type is text and there are lots of columns so I cannot handle with

```
update table1 set col1 = 0001 where col1 = 1;
```

and so on..

This seems easy question but after research,I could not find a solution. all I need is something like

```
foreach row in col1
if((int)row>0 and < 10)
then row = "000" + row;
```

All texts are infact integer value but I have to keep them as text. Whats sql query of above code?

Thanks

Comment: What data type is that column? If it's a number, it will never store leading zeros

Comment: No, its type is text. (such as string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `lpad()` function:

```
update table1
   set col1 = lpad(col1, 4, '0')
where length(col1) < 4;
```

---

But the real question is: why are you storing numbers as text values? That is almost always a bad choice.

Comment: Thanks, it works but there must be little changes. we must change col1 with '0'. This worked for me :

update table1 set col1= lpad(col1, 4, '0') where length(col1) < 4;

Comment: I have to use numbers as strings when the number actually represents a record ID with a specific character length, e.g. 3 vs "0003" ... silly, I know, but this is an inherited mess.